# How do i use a standard Query String + a Rewriter Route in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, query-string

I have ZF app that is utilizing a legacy Javascript at for some functionality. In order for this app to work i need to pass it a standard query string. So how can i use a standard Zend Route with a query string on it?

for example:

domain.com/my/routing/rule?legacyparm1=value&legacyparam2=value

It is not possible at this time to rewrite or restructure the js app as it is provided on an automated basis via a cron job from some other software package.

Whats the simplest way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything fancy—query string variables are passed to your controller using `$_GET` or `$this->getRequest()->getQuery()`. Just configure your route so that it matches everything before the `?` character. Using default routes, try the following URL:

> http://your-site/index/index?some-query-string

Comment: Youre right, i think its something in the JS app itself and the link formatting.

Thansk!